# Database is not being updated in line with changes in Challengeschema

Tags: mongodb, mongoose-schema

I tried adding likes/dislikes/satisfaction variables to my challengemodel, but when I look into my database (Atlas MongoDB) I can only see the ones that where there initially (title, description).

My database has a collection "challenges" with 4 challenges with the below structure (not likes/dislikes/satisfaction). How do I also include likes/dislikes/satisfaction with their default 0 value in here?

```
  QUERY RESULTS 1-4 OF 4
    _id:5eb98c06a1f08159842b430d
    title:"aaaaaaa"
    description:"aaaaaaaaa"
    __v:0
```

---

```
const challengeSchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    description: String,
    initiator: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:"User"},
    likes: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    dislikes: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    satisfaction: { type: Number, default: 0 }
})
```

---

```
//add challenge
router.post("/startchallenge", (req,res) => {
  Challenge
  .create({
    title: req.body.title,
    description: req.body.description,
    likes: req.body.likes,
    dislikes: req.body.dislikes,
    satisfaction: req.body.satisfaction
  })
  .then((response) => {
    res.json(response)
  })
  .catch(error => {
    res.json(error)
  })
})
```

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't a method to update the schema on existing documents, best you can do is update them manually if there aren't too many. Or create a script if there are many documents to update with the new schema

Comment: could you please provide a bit more detail? thank you in advance!